# Возникает ошибка при повторном отправлении

Tags: python, aiogram

При команде /start отправляется стикер и файл с музыкой , но когда повторно пишешь команду /start выдаёт ошибку :
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import keyboards as kb 
import os

bot = Bot(token = TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

fas = open('music/1.mp3', 'rb+')
sti = open('AnimatedSticker.tgs', 'rb')
   


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def music(message: types.Message):

    await bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio=fas)








if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: А зачем открывать на чтение и запись, когда можно открывать только на чтение?

Comment: У меня возникает исключение когда только на чтение UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 984: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит открывать `fas` на чтение и запись. Откройте только на чтение.

Плюс ко всему, Вы пытаетесь засунуть **поток** в `send_sticker` и `send_audio`. Попробуйте

```
fas = open('music/1.mp3', 'rb').read()
sti = open('AnimatedSticker.tgs', 'rb').read()
```